# Why does my coded email template look great in mailchimp but messed up in gmail?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, mailchimp

So I've coded an email template, placed it into a custom template in mail chimp. Looks great:
[image]

Now I've test emailed myself and it looks like this:

[image]

Not sure what I can do to make the text behave or how to make that image that is in the background show up, in the email the wrapper completely covers it.

But in mail on an iPhone, it looks great except the wrapper then becomes squished and jumps the "newsletter" and "September 2015" text to different lines.

And on an iPad it looks perfect, just the way i want it to.

What would be a good way to make it look good on all platforms? I don't know if its just a Gmail thing or screen issue?

Comment: I did this once.  I found that each email provider implemented a different set of css in them.   So I basically came up with a generic email, and then one for each of the different email providers that I knew id didn't work on.  Microsoft was the worst of them.

Comment: use the raw simple css , normal display no float. maybe table images href map will be better

Comment: use media css to implement for each. the standard one will only be 600px.

Comment: Are you using flexbox? Gmail doesn't support that, unfortunately..